# How do I make Auto Layout option to work in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need a small help. As suggested by the forums here, I used auto layout in all screens I develop. In my iOS app, I have around 11 screens. I developed with my iPhone which is iPhone 6s. Last week, when I went to deploy this in my tester iPhone, who uses iPhone 7s, I noticed that most of the screens, the alignment is not the same as my iPhone.

I have auto layout enabled and constraints are not changed. Please can anyone help me on how to make my screens uniform in all iPhone devices? I am using xcode 10.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such device as „iPhone 7S”. Did you mean „iPhone 7+”? Also - withou seeing your constraint code its impossible to say what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without knowing what it is you've done

Comment: Also, you've probably setup your autolayout constraints incorrectly. If correctly setup, the constraints should layout the views correctly on all screen sizes...

Comment: I am sorry. I meant iPhone 7+. I did not write any constraint code. As suggested by the forums, I just ticked the auto layout option in every screen. Apart from this I did not set any constraints. Am I missing anything here? Let me see if I can grab the images and put it here

Comment: "Just ticket the auto layout option" will not automatically make your UI adapt to different screen sizes. You should read up on how Autolayout constraints work. This link is good starting point. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help TheAppMentor. Sorry, I was not aware of this. I will work on it today and let the forum know the results